# Not able to start Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, devops

While trying to start Sonarqube./sonar.sh status it's showing -removed stale pid may I know reason for the error can anyone help me out with this and tell me  how to check out sonar logs as well

[Here the real issue I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48hhV.jpg)

Comment: What are the SonarQube logs saying? Could you share the web.log?